# How to surround multiple characters in a string with brackets {} in R?

Tags: r, subset, bioinformatics

I have a dataset containing genetic information.

```
structure(list(GenBank.Accession.version = structure(1:2, .Label = c("JH739893", 
"JH751134"), class = "factor"), set = c(17L, 116L), snp.po.200.low = c(5480045, 
-102), snp.po.200.up = c(5480464, 340), SNP.position = list(c(5480245L, 
5480263L), c(98L, 139L)), seq2 = c("TTACATGGCAAGCACTCAATCTGGCTGCAGGGTGTCTGGCCACATACAAAACAAATGCCAAGTCACCTCTTGTCCCAAGGATCAAGACAAATTTGGACAACAAACCACACTGGCAGCCCCCTAGAAGCTTTCAGATATTTTAATGCCATTGAGATGTAGCATCCAGTGTAGACATTATTAGAAGCACAGCAGTTGCACTCGCACCTCCAGGGTGTCCAACATATGCTGGATTCTGGCATTGCTCATGGCAAGTGAGTTGGTGAATTCACAACTAGCCAGGTCATGTCTTCATTGCAGCAGAAAACTCATCAGCATGTCAGGATGAGAAAAGTCAATACAAAGGAAATGTGGGGATGGGATGGGATGGGATGGGATGGGATGGGATGGGATGGGATGGGATGGGATGGGATAGGGGGGTAA", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAGGGAATTTAAGGAGTCCCAGAGACAGGAGAATTCAGGACAATTTGCACCAATCACTTGCTCCTGGAAAGGAAGGTTGGGCTGATTTGGGGTTGGTAAGCACAGACCTTTCATCCGTTCGTAGAAAGAAGGAAAATTAAATCTCATGGCCTGTTTGTGAAAGGAAATTGCCCAGAATAGCTCTGACAGAATAAGCTATTCCACAATAGCTCCCCATGCGGACACTCCAGCCACTTTGTTCCAGGCTAATTAGTGTGCTTCCAAGCGCAGTAATTATCCTGGAAGGGAAATCTCTCCTCTCCCACAAAGAGTGTTTGCATGGAG"
), seq.length = c(16983252L, 753L), pos.list = list(5480045:5480464, 
    1:340), SNP.pos.in.subset = list(c(201L, 219L), c(98L, 139L
))), .Names = c("GenBank.Accession.version", "set", "snp.po.200.low", 
"snp.po.200.up", "SNP.position", "seq2", "seq.length", "pos.list", 
"SNP.pos.in.subset"), row.names = c(17L, 116L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are 2 lines where in the first one, I have a genetic sequence (sequence of characters) that I want to modify. This string was subsetted from a longer DNA sequence (the original length was 16983252 for the first sequence).

SNP.position is giving me the position of character in the original string. SNP.pos.in.subset is giving me the same position but within the subset only (it's like if I was counting starting with 1 in my subset). So for the first sequence: 5480045 and 5480464 are referring to 201 ad 219 in the subsetted sequence.

I want to put some curly brackets around position 201 and 219 to locate the characters at these positions easily.

I created a script to do this.

```
add.target.snp = function(sequences, 
                          pos.start = 200, 
                          pos.end.added = 3, 
                          character.start = "{/",
                          character.end = "}") {
  old = as.character(sequences)
  for(i in 1:length(old)){
    up.else = SNP.position[i]+pos.end.added
    old[i] = gsub(paste0('^(.{',pos.start,'})(.*)$'), paste0('\\1',character.start,'\\2'), old[i])
    old[i] = gsub(paste0('^(.{',up.else,  '})(.*)$'), paste0('\\1',character.end,'\\2'), old[i])
  }

  return(old)
}
output.target = add.target.snp(sequences = df$seq2,
                               pos.start = df$SNP.pos.in.subset, 
                               pos.end.added = 3,
                               character.start = "{/",
                               character.end = "}")
```

But this script returns me this error:

```
 Error in gsub(paste0("^(.{", pos.start, "})(.*)$"), paste0("\\1", character.start,  : 
  invalid regular expression '^(.{c(201, 219)})(.*)$', reason 'Invalid contents of {}' In addition: Warning message:
In gsub(paste0("^(.{", pos.start, "})(.*)$"), paste0("\\1", character.start,  :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is there a way I could run my script, but include multiple values to surround with "{/my_value_at_position_201}" and "{/my_value_at_position_219}"?

The end result (for the second line in the data that I show) should be

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAAGGGAATTTAAGGAGTCCCAGAGACAGGAGAATTCAGGACAATTTGCACCAATCACTTGCTCCTGGAAAGGAAGGTTGGGC{/T}GATTTGGGGTTGGTAAGCACAGACCTTTCATCCGTTCGTA{/G}AAAGAAGGAAAATTAAATCTCATGGCCTGTTTGTGAAAGGAAATTGCCCAGAATAGCTCTGACAGAATAAGCTATTCCACAATAGCTCCCCATGCGGACACTCCAGCCACTTTGTTCCAGGCTAATTAGTGTGCTTCCAAGCGCAGTAATTATCCTGG
```

The other problem with my script is that if I add some characters in my vector (3 character in my case: "{/}"), it's going to shift the position of the second number (201, 219 + 3)... is there a way to add the brackets at once so that the numbers do not change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this. You want to use substring replacement. The base `substr` doesn't let you replace a zero length string, but something like should work:

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

add_bits <- function(sequences, 
  pos.start = 200, 
  pos.end.added = 3, 
  character.start = "{/",
  character.end = "}"
  ) {
    # this row allows for the fact that your string is growing.
    pos.start <- pos.start + c(0, cumsum(rep(nchar(character.start) + 
            nchar(character.end), length(pos.start) -1)))
    for (ps in pos.start) {
      stringi::stri_sub(sequences, ps, length = 0) <- character.start
      stringi::stri_sub(sequences, ps + pos.end.added, length = 0) <- character.end
    }
    sequences
}

tmp <- c("abcde", "123456789")
purrr::map2(tmp, list(c(2,5), 3), add_bits)
## [[1]]
## [1] "a{/b}cd{/e}fg"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "12{/3}4567"
```

Comment: They want to mark up multiple SNPs in a sequence, for example input would be `add_bits(tmp, c(2, 6), 3)`, with output for first string: `"a{/b}cde{/f}"`

Comment: My case looks more like: `add_bits(tmp, list(c(2,5),3), 3)`. Is there a way to deal with this? I've tried `add_bits(tmp, unlist(list(c(2,5),3)), 3)` but it doesn't work. It breaks the association of SNP position and sequence. I've also tried putting the "unlist" inside the function, but it wasn't working either...

Comment: I understand, so you want multiple elements per string to have the extra characters.

Comment: Yes! The best best best would be to make it generalizable with multiple entries such that `"abcde"` modified with `"2"` and `"4"` would end up being `"a{/b}c{/d}e"` and `"fghij"` modified with `"3"` would be `"fg{/h}ij"` and so on. I have multiple numbers or sometimes, only one, for my strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try using base packages:

```
add.target.snp = function(sequences, pos.start = NA,
                          character.start = "{/", character.end = "}"){
  # check input
  pos.start <- sort(pos.start[ pos.start <= nchar(sequences)])

  # split on SNP positions
  snps <- substring(
    sequences, c(1, pos.start), c(pos.start - 1, nchar(sequences)))
  # exclude "" SNP strings
  snps <- snps[ snps != "" ]

  # take 1st char and wrap, then paste the rest as is
  x0 <- ""
  if(!1 %in% pos.start){
    x0 <- snps[1]
    snps <- snps[2:length(snps)]}

  res <- sapply(snps, function(snp){
    x1 <- substr(snp, 1, 1)
    x2 <- substr(snp, 2, max(2, nchar(snp)))

    paste0(paste0(character.start, x1, character.end), x2)})

  # return
  paste(c(x0, res), collapse = "")
}


tmp <- c("abcde", "123456789")
purrr::map2(tmp, list(c(2,5), 3), add.target.snp)
# [[1]]
# [1] "a{/b}cd{/e}"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "12{/3}456789"
```